# y = b1 * max(x1, b2*x1 + b3*x2)

Tags: r, regression

I would like to fit a regression such as

$     y = b_1 \times \max(x_1, b_2 \cdot x_1 + b_3 \cdot  x_2) $

This model assumes that a contour plot as a function of $x_1$ and $x_2$ looks like below

[image]

$b_1$ determines how steeply $y$ increases as $x_1$ and $x_2$ increases.

When $b_2$ is zero, the horizontal line is really horizontal. 
$b_2$ determines the slope.

$b_3$ determines the ratio of height and width of the contour rectangle.

Can I fit this function using R or any other statistical package?

Comment: The R function is something like `nls(y ~ b1 * pmax(x1, b2 * x1 + b3 * x2))` but you'll probably looking for more detailed answer.